# Tampering detection using data hiding

Tags: image-processing, video

I am planning to do a project on data hiding using codeword substitution in encrypted video.

So as an enhancement I am planning to use this data hiding technique for tampering detection, for which I'll be extracting some information from the frames and will be hiding it in a selected frame.

I am actually using the concept of digital signature. The thing is that I am in search of a data to hide. A data which has to be extracted from the frames  for verification on the receiver side.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to DSP stackexchange. You forgot to actually ask a **precise question** (or actually, you did not ask *any* question).

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm understanding you correctly:

What you want to do is *hide* data in the *encrypted* version of a video?

That will break everything. Simple as that. A very important aspect to good encryption is that a small change in the cleartext data (your unencrypted video) will result in a completely changed encrypted video; the same applies in the other direction -- you change a bit in your encrypted video stream, you completely break at least one block of cleartext data. That's not hiding -- in fact, it's the opposite.

Hence, I think your approach is mathematically doomed; but maybe, I'm just misunderstanding.